# Configuring Play Framework 2.0 conf file in Intellij IDEA 14.1.4

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework, configuration

I'm using Intellij IDEA 14.1.4 to develop a Play 2.x application and I was wondering if it's possible to somehow configure the conf file used by Play. I'd like to do something similar to what's described here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ProductionConfiguration.

```
$ /path/to/bin/<project-name> -Dconfig.file=/opt/conf/prod.conf
```

Is is possible to somehow set up a configuration in IDEA? I've looked at the configuration settings in IDEA, but I haven't found anything to specify the conf file. I've also tried the IDEA forum but unfortunately nobody has answered so far.

Here's the configuration window in IDEA:

[image: IDEA config screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the "run configuration" and specify additional parameters. Recent versions of IDEA use `sbt` to run Play Applications, which allows you to add additional parameters.

Simply add `-Dconfig.resource=idea.conf` and create an idea.conf-file containing the development configuration.

Comment: Could you please specify, how to add this to the sbt? I suppose I should add some line to my build.sbt file but I don't know how to write it. As to 'edit configuration', I haven't found any place to input additional parameters there.

Comment: You don't add it to the sbt. You add it to the run configuration in IDEA.

Comment: Well, I guess I don't understand what 'run configuration' means. I've updated my post with the screen of what I look at. Should I look somewhere else?

Comment: Add it to the "JVM Options".